# Most concise way to de-stringify HTML and extract data attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some HTML code as a string. For example,

```
<button data-a=12 data-b=444 data-c='xyz'>Reply</button>
```

This string is stored in a variable in Javascript. There can be any number of data attributes in the string. The value of each attribute can be anything. I have to extract the value of a particular attribute, say `data-b`, for this case.

Apart from the obvious string manipulations, is there a more concise way to somehow de-stringify this "stringy" HTML code and extract the data-attribute value using jQuery? Is there another better way to do this? Which one is the best with regards to efficiency and readability?

Edit: The values of some of these attributes (other than the one I want to extract) come from user input. I use a sanitizer library before rendering those inputs as data attribute values, so the string should be XSS safe, but it can look very weird. For example, this string could be,

`<button data-a=10 data-b=76 data-c='>1' alert(502); data-d=34>Reply</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For elegance, I'd prefer to use DOMParser:

```js
const str = `<button data-a=12 data-b=444 data-c='xyz'>Reply</button>`;
const { b } = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').querySelector('button').dataset;
console.log(b);
```

It's not entirely concise, but it's easy to understand.

If the string is trustworthy (and XSS isn't something to worry about) you could also create an element and set its `innerHTML` to the input string with jQuery:

```js
const str = `<button data-a=12 data-b=444 data-c='xyz'>Reply</button>`;
const b = $(str).data('b');
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(but if the input isn't trustworthy, the jQuery approach is a security risk:

```js
const str = `<img src onerror="alert('evil')" data-a=12 data-b=444 data-c='xyz' />`;
const b = $(str).data('b');
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that XSS safeness would be a parameter to judge approaches. I have edited the question now to better reflect my situation. Does the DOMParser method still hold good after the edit?

Comment: If the input is sanitized, and you trust the sanitizer, then either approach works. Though, I'd personally prefer DOMParser because it doesn't require relying on a big external library - it's completely built into the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much!